# How to check values from child object

Tags: account, order, iteration

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do the following.

The **Account** object is the parent of the **Order** object.

The **Order** object has a field called '**Status**'.

The **Status** field, a drop down field, has several values.

The **Account** can have many **Order** records (one-to-many relationship).

I need to check for every **Account** that I pass from a **Set** collection the following.

If all **Order** records that are children of an **Account** have the `Status = 'Completed'`, move those **Accounts** to another **Set** collection.

What will be the best way to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thought that comes to me is to have two rollup summary fields (via standard rollups, or [declarative rollups](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)). One to count the number of `Orders` under a given `Account`, and another one to count the number of `Orders` which are complete.

With that, the logic that you're looking to implement becomes trivial (for all accounts in trigger.new, check to see if `Count1` == `Count2`. Put into one set if true, the other set if false).

Comment: Thanks for your response Derek. The part you are mentioning I already have in place exactly as you are suggesting. What puzzles me is how can I check if all Orders related to an Account have their Status set to Completed. That is what I'm missing in my code.

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo I don't understand what you're stuck on. If you have one summary field that counts _all_ `Orders`, and a second summary field that counts only `Orders` where `Status == 'Complete'`, then checking if all `Orders` related to the `Account` are complete is simply a matter of checking if `account.<Count of All Orders> == account.<Count of Completed Orders>`. Are you asking about how to get the count of completed orders?

Comment: if you had to code this by using maps or use the declarative rollups, what would you feel is the best option considering efficiency and stability?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo The DLRS tool is fairly widely used, and has been around for a number of years, so I'd say that would be the more stable option. Efficiency should be about the same. The only real downside to using DLRS is that it creates a separate trigger. If you're looking to adhere to the idea of  "One Trigger per Object", then you might need to integrate the trigger generated by the DLRS tool (at the cost of losing the ability to declaratively modify the rollup). DLRS tool may also not work too well if you're using a trigger framework.